# How to filter local requests in asp.net web api?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm having a situation that is getting kind of annoying with asp.net web api. The thing is i have an API which is already in production, however I'm constantly making changing and deploying again.

I have a filter, which takes care of checking if the request is https, that works awesome on production, but when requests are local the filter blocks all http requests, which is not what I want. I would like to allow local requests with http. I have a filter which does the exact same thing on MVC3, and I can do something like:

```
filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsLocal
```

Is there any work around to this problem?

Comment: why's you don't access from localhost using https?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you are using webhost i.e hosting webapi in asp.net, you can access the HttpContext using

```
HttpContextBase httpContextBase;
request.Properties.TryGetValue("MS_HttpContext", out httpContextBase);
```

You can then use `httpContextBase.Request.IsLocal` to determine if the request is local.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an extension method to access the value within the Request.Properties Dictionary. For example:

```
public static class HttpRequestExtensions
{
   public static bool IsLocal(this HttpRequestMessage request)
   {
       var flag = request.Properties["MS_IsLocal"] as Lazy<bool>;
       return flag != null && flag.Value;
   }
}
```

This has the added benefit of also working when self-hosting.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use the **IsLocal** extension method of the **HttpRequestMessage**. [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httprequestmessageextensions.islocal(v=vs.118).aspx)

For example:

```
using System.Net.Http;

...

public void PostUser(User user) 
{
    if (!base.Request.IsLocal())    
    { 
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

MS_Islocal property was not available to me instead this worked -

```
if (Request != null && Request.Properties.ContainsKey("MS_RequestContext")){
                    var context = Request.Properties["MS_RequestContext"] as HttpRequestContext;
                    return context.IsLocal;
                }
                return false;
```