# HttpRequestMessage.IsLocal() false on one site true on another on the same server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, windows-server

I'm running asp.net web api application on a windows server. I have 2 sites with different ip-addresses. When the application is deployed on one of the sites the IsLocal is true, when deploying on the other site it is false.

Checking the source code, it boils down to this:

```
    [DllImport("aspnet_state.exe", CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]
    internal static extern void STWNDGetLocalAddress(IntPtr tracker, StringBuilder buf);
```

This is the method that returns the local address, why isn't the second ip valid? The network config looks like this (the .79 ip-address is the one that IsLocal returns false for)

[image]

How do I get the IsLocal to consider the second ip?

Comment: Though I could not find an answer to this question. There is a workaround to achieve your need @http://www.strathweb.com/2013/01/adding-request-islocal-to-asp-net-web-api/

Comment: That looks neat, but that solution uses the STWNDGetLocalAddress too, so I assume it won't deliver the .79 address.

Comment: Did you took a look @http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11849501/how-to-filter-local-requests-in-asp-net-web-api. Just a suggestion. If already went through it please skip

Answer (score 4):

`IsLocal` returns true in any of three conditions:

- The request came from 127.0.0.1
- The request came from localhost
- The request came from the same IP as the server IP

Your first step should be to log out the IP of incoming requests so you can be certain what Web API considers to be the source.

Comment: It's not localhost and it's not 127.0.0.1. But the ip-address is assigned to a adpter on the server. But why isn't that local. I will add some logging to get more context. If the server have more than one ip-address, what is "server ip"?